# Linux Mint 20: apt and apt-utils have mismatched versions

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

I'm using Linux Mint 20, and I can no longer get software updates because `apt` and `apt-utils` have mismatched versions.  This is the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 2.0.4) but 2.0.5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I did try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but that just prints usage info.

I'm not sure precisely how this happened.  I've been applying upgrades using the Update Manager as usual without problems for the last several months.

Advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@psusi's suggestion was the answer for me.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Worked nicely. Thank you. I would have commented, but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much!